# Automate BigQuery schema/table creation from csv file using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to automatically create BQ table/s from a desktop folder containing csv files( i.e Automatically create schema and load to a new table)

If the same file is loaded next time just update the existing table, if a new file is loaded then create a new table. Is it possible to automate using Python?.

Current Code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 from google.cloud import bigquery 
 def bqDataLoad(event, context): 
  bucketName = event['test_vs'] 
  blobName = event['gf-dev-models'] 
  fileName = "gs://" + bucketName + "/" + blobName 
  bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client() 
  tableRef = bigqueryClient.dataset("gf-dev-models-204097").table("test_vs") 
  dataFrame = pd.read_csv(fileName) bigqueryJob = bigqueryClient.load_table_from_dataframe(dataFrame, tableRef) bigqueryJob.result()
#Project id = gf-dev-models
#dataset = gf-dev-models-204097 
#table name = want a new table created
```

Comment: @Soumendra Mishra - How do I pass credentials within this code and how do I create a schema automatically if I dont have an existing table in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer with reference to your question in the comment section:

**Credential in Code:**
You can create a service account with desired BigQuery roles and download JSON key file (example: data-lab.json).

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "data-lab.json"
```

**Create Schema Automatically & Loading data to BigQuery:**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client()
jobConfig = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
jobConfig.skip_leading_rows = 1
jobConfig.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
jobConfig.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND   
jobConfig.autodetect=True

datasetName = "dataset-name"
targetTable = "table-name"
uri = "gs://bucket-name/file-name.csv"
tableRef = bigqueryClient.dataset(datasetName).table(targetTable)
bigqueryJob = bigqueryClient.load_table_from_uri(uri, tableRef, job_config=jobConfig)
bigqueryJob.result()
```